# Why kernel code change on load? Are pointer addresses change on load?

Tags: assembly, memory, linux-kernel

I took the kernel code from the memory and the zmlinuz (vmlinuz) file from the disk. I decompressed the vmlinuz to elf file and I compared the code sections of the memory and the disk files. 
I found that the code in the memory has changed a little bit.
The changes between the code in memory and the code on the disk were pointers to strings.
The change is indicated in the following image in the red square:

[image]

The value "02 82" changed to "62 a8".

The offset of all code changes was fixed (0x6026). 
I'm trying to figure out why the change is happening? Is there a mapping in the elf file to all the places that made this change? 
How does the kernel loader know where to make the change of address?

Thank you

Comment: Are you asking why the addresses on the ELF file differ from the ones in memory? That's normal relocation, also the kernel address space can/is randomized for security purposes. The ELF has all the information for the loader to patch the code once it has selected a random loading address.

Comment: @MargaretBloom - Where can I found the mapping of all the changes? How does the loader know where to update the addresses? Is it running all the code and looking for addresses that need updating or is there a table that maps the places with the addresses?

Comment: ELF includes a way to store a table of relocation entries.  You'd see the same thing in user-space for something like global `void *p = p;` in a PIE executable (statically initialized pointer to itself), or in hand-written asm `mov rax, offset some_symbol` to get a `mov r64, imm64` with an absolute address.  Kernel code can use sign-extended imm32 relocations because it's loaded in the high 2GiB of virtual address space.

Comment: @DinDan The kernel file contains a relocation table where all these changes are listed.  They are resolved when the kernel is loaded.  Try `objdump -r vmlinux` to list them.

Comment: @fuz this command returns empty list.

Comment: @DinDan Interesting.  Perhaps they use some other mechanism?

Comment: @fuz there is no loader to resolve relocations when you boot into the kernel. The kernel is the first thing that runs after the bootloader, and it decompresses and relocates itself.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli, there is a loader **inside** the kernel which resolves the relocations.

Comment: @0andriy yea, that's what I meant, it's not external, it's embedded in the kernel itself and is not the "usual" loader we all know.